# How do In stretch my div to fit the picture inside it?

Tags: css, image, html

I created an imagemap inside a div, but the div doesn't fit the image.  Considering the div is inside a template I can't edit, how do I fix this so the image fits inside the div and not outside it?

[Raja dance links](http://www.rajadance.com/links.html)

Comment: Also why is there a brown frame around the picture?  I definitely have border=0 in there?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
overflow:auto;
```

to #templatemo_welcome_area for the div to "overflow" the image.

Looks good in chrome and FFox now for me.

Comment: check in all browsers. This is an old trick for FFox - but if you push the DOM too hard (cascade in adjustments) you might get scroll handles. KISS FTW in CSS.

Comment: Great, please accept the answer and don't discount the power of clear:both and display parameters listed by others.

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is floating, it's normal that your div doesn't fit.

If you want to keep your `float:right`, you should add this to your CSS :

```
#templatemo_welcome_area:after { 
    content: '';
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: But why is there a brown box around the image?

Comment: Your image has a `border` set - [Here is where](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s13/sh/ff01e527-cfeb-4f77-ac28-278c2788272f/3ea70d29b6821a5ffdd9d5f5feb6c373)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are talking about `#templatemo_welcome_area`, you could start by adding `display:inline-block` to it.